# Send email function to multiple users

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, email

I have sscript function to send enamils like this:

```
function sendEmail() {

var appweburl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";


var fieldName = "Notificar a";
var body = "Descripción";
var _body = $("textarea[title^='" + body + "']");

var fullURL = window.location.href
var url = new URL(fullURL ); 
var ID = url.searchParams.get("ID");

var arrEmailID = [];
var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
var emailSpan = $(_PeoplePicker).find('.sp-peoplepicker-userSpan');
var _sid ="";
if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
    $(emailSpan).each(function (){
             _sid = $(this).attr('sid');
            _sid =  _sid.split("|")[2];
            // alert(_sid.split("|")[2]);
             arrEmailID.push(_sid);
        })

         // _sid = _sid = $(emailSpan).attr('sid');
         // _sid =  _sid.split("|")[2];
} else {
       alert("null");
}

        var fieldUsuario = _sid;
        var fromMail = 'bocar@bocar.com';
        var subject = 'Tarea Editada: ' + 'ID: ' +ID + ' ' + _body.val();
        var body = 'Se ha editado la tarea: '+ 'ID: ' + ID+ ' ' + 'Descripción: ' + _body.val() ;    

       var arraySemicolon =  arrEmailID.join(";");

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': fromMail,
                'To': { 'results': ['user1@onmicrosoft.com'] },
                'Body': body, 
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.results;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

If I send in `To` action only one email it works correctly. Problem starts when I try to send more than one as:

```
'To': { 'results': ['user1@onmicrosoft.com;user2@onmicrosoft.com'] },
```

I don´t know why I don´t receiving email when I use multiple users. Any one have an idea why?

I also try to use comma separator as:

```
'To': { 'results': ['user1@onmicrosoft.com,user2@onmicrosoft.com'] },
```

But it shouldn´t work

Update:

[image]

Comment: You are doing it right, just you have to separate all email address in single quote each. 'To': { 'results': ['user1@onmicrosoft.com','user2@onmicrosoft.com'] },

Comment: How can I achieve that? my comma separated array is `var arrEmailID = [];` @GopalZadafiya

Comment: I would recommend you some modification in arrEmailID so that You can have above format in ready position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right, just you have to separate all email address in **single quote** each.

**Updated code block :**

```
if (emailSpan.length > 0) {
    $(emailSpan).each(function (){
             _sid = $(this).attr('sid');
             _sid =  _sid.split("|")[2];
             arrEmailID.push("'" + _sid + "'");
        });
       arrEmailID = arrEmailID.join(",");
} else {
       alert("null");
}
```

Comment: I try it but when it try to push second email I get: Uncaught type error: arrEmailID.push is not a function

Comment: In which browser are you executing this code ?

Comment: I debbuging in google chrome

Comment: Is your variable declaration is like var arrEmailID = []; ?

Comment: yes sir, as my code in my question

Comment: @David,can you please add the required code in comment section ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77018/discussion-between-gopal-zadafiya-and-david).